# Why do I not have any directory except 'home' with new user?

Tags: user-management, useradd

I created a new non-root user and did the following:

```
useradd -m newusername 
passwd newusername 
usermod -a -G sudo newusername 
chsh -s /bin/bash newusername
```

I need to install software as a non-root user, but when I'm logged in as that user,

```
cd Downloads
```

does nothing. The directory doesn't exist. Did I do something wrong when creating the user, or am I missing something?

```
cd /home/newusername/Downloads
```

does not work either.

Comment: @JonasCz I'm going to try that post you mentioned. I think I made a mistake when making my home directory. Thanks for sharing that.

Comment: @JonasCz That didn't work. I did the exact commands, but when I try to login (su - newusername), all I get is a '$'.

Comment: I don't know what could be wrong in that case.  Although since you say you made a mistake, you could just delete the user and start over, or perhaps use the graphical user management / administration utility ?

Comment: You usually use the friendlier `adduser` instead of `useradd`.

Comment: When you type `cd /home/newusername/Downloads` what makes you think it didn't work? What is the output of `pwd` after you did `cd /home/newusername/Downloads`?

Answer (score 1):

Downloads, Desktop, Music, and the other directories are not part of `/etc/skel`, and they are not created by `useradd` (or `adduser`, for that matter). These directories, collectively known as the [XDG user directories](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_user_directories) can be created using the [`xdg-user-dirs-update`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xdg-user-dirs-update) command, run as that user:

```
sudo -iu <user> xdg-user-dirs-update
```

For example:

```
# useradd -m foo
# getent passwd foo
foo:x:1001:1003::/home/foo:/bin/bash
# ls /home/foo/ -l
total 0
# sudo -iu foo xdg-user-dirs-update
# ls /home/foo/ -l                 
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 foo foo 4096 Jun  7 14:43 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 foo foo 4096 Jun  7 14:43 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 foo foo 4096 Jun  7 14:43 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 2 foo foo 4096 Jun  7 14:43 Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 foo foo 4096 Jun  7 14:43 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 foo foo 4096 Jun  7 14:43 Public
drwxr-xr-x 2 foo foo 4096 Jun  7 14:43 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 2 foo foo 4096 Jun  7 14:43 Videos
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out. I deleted that user and started over.

```
useradd -m newusername
passwd newusername 
usermod -a -G sudo newusername 
chsh -s /bin/bash newusername
```

Then

```
su - newusername
```

And I get

```
newusername@kali:~$
```

And I'm able to

```
cd Downloads
```

:-)

Comment: Nevermind. It only lasts for that session. If I shutdown it's back to the same problem. This is getting frustrating and I can't seem to find a similar question anywhere.